# Emacs evil-mode yank and paste entire lines

Tags: emacs, evil

In Vim I can do this:

Example text (cursor is on the semicolon):

```
void test(){
  corner[0]=23;
}
```

In Vim, the command `ddP...` results in the following change (cursor ends up on the first `c`):

```
void test(){
  corner[0]=23;
  corner[0]=23;
  corner[0]=23;
  corner[0]=23;
}
```

However in Emacs + evil-mode, `ddP...` results in:

```
void test(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  corner[0]=23  corner[0]=23  corner[0]=23  corner[0]=23;                                                                                                                                                                                   
;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

If I instead type `ddp...` this is the result (cursor ends up on the last line):

```
void test(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }  corner[0]=23;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    corner[0]=23;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    corner[0]=23;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    corner[0]=23;
```

### How can I set this like Vim?

Comment: This is not the case for me. Evil emulates vim for me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the exact same problem, and it turns out that `gpaste` cause the problem.